# Cannot read property '$scope' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-scope

When I receive a html content in angular app, I inject it in the html document, but then can't get it. Example [minimized code on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V8WJqR?p=preview) and in [javascript](http://plnkr.co/edit/6TkZL3?p=preview)

I have next controller:

```
class ReadCtrl

  constructor: (@$scope, @$rootScope, @$compile, @$sce, @$window, @webService) ->
    @getData()

  getData: ->
    promise = @webService.getBookText()
    promise.then @success, @error

  success: (response) =>
    @$scope.html = response.data
    @$scope.trustedHtml = @$sce.trustAsHtml(@$scope.html)
    console.log $('.book_contents').first().children()

ReadCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$rootScope", "$compile", '$sce', "$window", "webService"]
angular.module("bookReader").controller "ReadCtrl", ReadCtrl
```

Method success save html to variable trustedHtml, and then it binds to view:

```
<div class="br_container">
  <div class="br_source_container" ng-bind-html="trustedHtml">
  </div>
</div>
```

Content shows, but this `console.log $('.book_contents').first().children()` has zero elements. And when i try to insert something like `@$rootScope.$digest()` the error throws:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

That because of `=>` in method, which compiles to:

```
  __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };
  this.success = __bind(this.success, this);
```

So if I change `=>` to `->` there is another error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property '$scope' of undefined
```

In the first line of `success` function. So `this` is undefined in `success` function, perhaps because it is called with promise.

Another method with `$('.br_source_container').html(@$compile(@$scope.trustedHtml)(scope))` occurs the same errors.

So, I need to get DOM html of the inserted part.

Comment: can't run console.log() inside a controller right after setting a scope value and expect digest cycle to be completed. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: stilt can't do this. Even this simplified version http://plnkr.co/edit/V8WJqR?p=preview doesn't work.

Comment: I don't play with coffee well...throwing error can't initalize bookReader module...must be syntax problem or somehting

Comment: Fine, it works on plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/V8WJqR?p=preview

Comment: The same in js http://plnkr.co/edit/6TkZL3?p=preview

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do...works fine here, I added slight delay. Need a digest cycle to repaint DOM  http://plnkr.co/edit/M7R0BebZnqIUJJzb6g9x?p=preview

Comment: Yes, thanks. I saw this somewhere on stack, but didn't given a value. It works even with 0 delay. Im my project also works with 0 even for big book. You can place it to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem solves with `timeout` respectful for [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl)
This how it wors